# Symfony: Hide/Show form element dependent on dropdown selection with database entries

Tags: forms, symfony, dependencies, show-hide

I hope my title is proper: I have a dropdown, that comes from a form as an EntityType and the values are from an entity class. Code:

```
   ->add('type', EntityType::class, array(
      'class' => 'DocumentBundle:DocumentType',
      'label' => 'label.type',
      'property' => 'translationKey',
      'required' => true,
      'multiple' => false,
      'expanded' => false,
      'empty_value' => 'label.select_type',
      'choice_translation_domain' => 'Documents'
      ))
  ->add('vka_number', 'text', array(
      'label' => 'label.vka_number',
      'required' => false,
      'translation_domain' => 'Documents'))
```

the second one is a text field (vka_number) that I only want to be shown when a specific value from that dropdown is selected
in my twig template I render the elements:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6" id="documentDropdown">
    {{ form_row(form.type) }}
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6" id="vka">
    {{ form_row(form.vka_number) }}
  </div>
</div>
```

I was thinking about a javascript function like that:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#documentDropdown').on('change', function(){
       if (this.value == 'Contract')
       {
         $('#vka').show();
       }
        else {
         $('#vka').hide();
       }
    });
    });
    </script>
```

but it's not working and I think this is because it can't access the values from the dropdown since they are not hard coded but database entries. 
'Contract' would be the entry (id=1) that "makes" the vka_number text field appear.

Comment: May I ask when do you want to hide the `#vka` id? I see now that the Contract item in the list is actually a `value="1"` but not `value="Contract"` which is what you wanted to query on. i updated my jsfiddle to work on only `value="1"`. So in other words: `if (this.value == '1')`

Comment: I want it always to be hidden except for the situation when "Contract" is selected, which - in my database- has the id 1. I was just trying out different possibilities to access my selected values..

Comment: I updated my answer and the jsfiddle. It should work now on the Contract value which is `1`. Try it.

Comment: thank you @AlvinBunk your JSFiddle is now working for me, too. But still in my project where it is not hard coded, it's not working.. :/

Comment: Have you tried debugging in FireFox by setting a breakpoint on the if statement: `if (this.value == '1')` and then single-stepping to see what happens. I would expect you to do this first before posting a comment stating "it's not working"...

Comment: I don't know how to debug it. I don't use firefox but chromium on linux. I'm still pretty sure that it's not getting the ID from my data because they are not in the same twig file but only on the database. As you can see from my code above, I nowhere ever mentioned the single choices with their names and IDs so I wouldn't understand why javascript could just compare this.value == 1. There is never a value set like when hardcoding it (e.g. your jsfiddle) so it wouldn't have this data..

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my javascript function that eventually solved my problem.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#type ').change(function() {
         if ($('select[id$="_type"]>option:selected').text() == "Contract") {
            $('#vka_number ').show();
        }
        else {
          $('#vka_number').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes this would work. Glad you got it working! Taking the time to learn how to debug Javascript/jQuery will help you in the long run.

Comment: Thanks @AlvinBunk. Yes I'm definitely working on that and try to get better! :)

Answer (score 1):

I copied the html code from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46322707/how-to-display-selected-item-from-bootstrap-dropdown) Sonja, and you seem to be continuing to ask the same question. I used that code in this jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/alvinbunk/to9qodwx/

You can use jsfiddle to experiment with your jQuery code to figure out what is wrong. As you can see the code does work and does hide the `vka` id division. it really has nothing to do with the fact that values are from the database. Make sure you don't have duplicate ids in various elements in your html code. Use "view source" in your browser to see the rendered code.

By the way I spent at least 15 minutes on this answer, and also 15 - 30 minutes on the other one. be aware that people on StackOverflow are very busy, and it's good to ask your questions very clearly.

---

EDIT #2 - Based on comments

Use this jQuery code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#documentDropdown').on('change', function(){
   if (this.value == '1')
   {
     $('#vka').show();
   }
    else {
     $('#vka').hide();
   }
});
});
</script>
```

That should work.

Comment: I opened a new question since the other one was concerning a different topic (displaying dropdown content) and I honestly don't know how I could be more precise. I provided every code I have and explained exactly explained what my problem is.. your JS fiddle is not working when I try it. Especially since I now changed my code (you made the fiddle with the hard coded version but now I'm using the form-type version)

Comment: Do you mean "your code" is not working with the changes from my jsfiddle? That is different that the jsfiddle not working! I just checked again and the jsfiddle does work as expected. In other words you select something from the list and it hides the `vka` id div tag section. If it's really "your code" that is not working: like I said post your "view source" html code somewhere so we can see it. Can you post on pastebin and add a link? Or create a new jsfiddle?

Comment: I don't know how else I can explain it: my code relays on database entries. I don't know how i could connect a JSfiddle to these data.For me neither your JSfiddle nor my code is working. Simply the question: how can javascript access the selected values if they are not actually in my twig code but only in my DB. As you can see above I get the values via my form. in my twig file there is no part where the elements of the dropdown are named so that my JS could relate on that. Is the function at all correct like that and if yes the ='Contract' part is wrong and I'd like to know how to change it..

Comment: Thank you Alvin I figured it out now. I just made some changes to it and posted my final solution below, but your function definitely works now :) only thing I don't like/figured out so far is: when I once selected another choice than "Contract" (value 1), the vka field is hidden and when then selection "Contract" it doesn't reappear. Do I need a loop for this? Or is there a neater function that helps me achieving this?

Comment: Oh no, I just figured that it's actually not working correctly. It doesn't matter which choice I select, the vka field is I changed it to the solution below with ('select[id$="_type"]>option:selected')